# Why npm give me this output?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm

I have a problem with ionic, npm ecc.
I want to write an app with Ionic framework using Angular.
I installed Node.js, ionic, angular, @ionic/angular, native-run, cordova-res, @capacitor/camera, @capacitor/storage, @capacitor/filesystem.
But when I put the command `ionic start` this is the output:

```
? Starter template: sidemenu
√ Preparing directory .\ludolambru in 1.97ms
√ Downloading and extracting sidemenu starter in 367.60ms
> ionic integrations enable capacitor --quiet -- ludolambru io.ionic.starter
> npm.cmd i --save -E @capacitor/core@latest
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: ionic-app-base@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@12.1.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   dev @angular/compiler@"~12.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler@"12.1.5" from @angular/compiler-cli@12.1.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!     dev @angular/compiler-cli@"~12.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^12.0.0 || ^12.1.0-next" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.1.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!       dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~12.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"12.2.6" from @angular/localize@12.2.6
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/localize
npm ERR!   peerOptional @angular/localize@"^12.0.0 || ^12.1.0-next" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.1.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~12.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\latin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full     report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\latin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-17T09_15_32_264Z-    debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

        npm.cmd i --save -E @capacitor/core@latest exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.

Installing dependencies may take several minutes.

  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

        Ionic Appflow, the mobile DevOps solution by Ionic

           Continuously build, deploy, and ship apps
        Focus on building apps while we automate the rest

        Learn more: https://ion.link/appflow

  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────


> npm.cmd i
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: ludolambru@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@12.1.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
npm ERR!   dev @angular/compiler@"~12.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler@"12.1.5" from @angular/compiler-cli@12.1.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!     dev @angular/compiler-cli@"~12.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^12.0.0 || ^12.1.0-next" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@12.1.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!       dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~12.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"12.2.6" from @angular/localize@12.2.6
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/localize
npm ERR!   peerOptional @angular/localize@"^12.0.0 || ^12.1.0-next" from @angular-    devkit/build-angular@12.1.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~12.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I tried to serch it on google but i didn't find anything. I don't know if I forgot some packages or I was wrong something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incompatible dependencies,

You have `@angular/compiler@12.1.5` installed but `@angular/localize@12.2.6` requires `@angular/compiler@"12.2.6"`. I'm guessing you have package.json that looks like:

```json
"@angular/compiler":"12.1.5",
"@angular/localize":"12.2.6"
```

You'll need to change that so that they can be resolved. It is hard to give explicit advice without seeing your package.json.

Comment: ionic start --force might work but resolving deps correctly as suggested is the better solution

Comment: Also worth checking that he is not using some dinosaur version of Node

Comment: My node version is :v14.17.6 and my npm version is: 7.5.4. I can't put --force because the command is part of a stream of commands that ionic put when I run "ionic start". Where can I find the  package.json? In the ionic's config directory?

Comment: package.json is in the root of your application typically. It's where you run `npm install` from.

Comment: i found two files, I up the files on google drive becouse one of that file are very long.

Comment: I think you need to [read up on what a package.json is](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json)

Comment: now it works i redownload the all things and now it works.